# Premade database. Keeps forcing close. Sqlite errors

Tags: android, database

I have made a premade one and am trying to use it from the asset folder but keep getting errors.

```
05-02 14:58:44.771: E/Database(573): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.MC.ChemPal/databases/ChemPaldb.db", &handle, 2, NULL) failed

05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MC.ChemPal/com.MC.ChemPal.sqlView}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.MC.ChemPal.sqlStuff.openDatabase(sqlStuff.java:148)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.MC.ChemPal.sqlView.onCreate(sqlView.java:20)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-02 14:58:44.792: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  ... 11 more
```

The log cats above go with the code below i'm trying to use a database i made in sqlite browser I have added the android meta data and a integer primary key is present in the database. It causes the app to crash whenever i try to do anything relating to my db.

```
package com.MC.ChemPal;


import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class sqlStuff extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String KEY_ROWID= "_id";
public static final String KEY_SYSNAME= "systematic_name";
public static final String KEY_MOLARMASS= "molar_mass";
public static final String KEY_GROUP = "groups";
public static final String KEY_MP ="melting_point";
public static final String KEY_BP ="boiling_point";
public static final String KEY_COMNAME="general_name";
public static final String KEY_CONELEMENTS="elements_included_C_H";






 private SQLiteDatabase ChemPal;
 private static String DATABASE_NAME = "ChemPaldb.db";
 private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.MC.ChemPal/databases/";
 private static String DATABASE_TABLE = "ChemTable";



    private SQLiteDatabase sampleDatabase; 
    private final Context androidContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the   application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public sqlStuff(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.androidContext = context;
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }
        else {



            // Create a skeleton database
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDatabase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you  open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDatabase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = androidContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        sampleDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(sampleDatabase != null)
                sampleDatabase.close();

            super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO: Write routines to remove and overwrite the database on an upgrade
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /***
     * A sample function that returns a Cursor from the database.  Should use the Data Provider pattern, but used for brevity
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getUserTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM User", null);
        return cursor;
    }





public long createEntry(String SYSNAME, String MOLMASS, String GROUP, String MP, String BP, String COMNAME, String CONELEMENTS){
      //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_SYSNAME, SYSNAME);
    cv.put(KEY_MOLARMASS, MOLMASS);
    cv.put(KEY_GROUP, GROUP);
    cv.put(KEY_MP, MP);
    cv.put(KEY_BP, BP);
    cv.put(KEY_COMNAME, COMNAME); 
    cv.put(KEY_CONELEMENTS, CONELEMENTS);
    return ChemPal.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String TAG = "my tag";
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        return 0;

    }

}
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID , KEY_SYSNAME , KEY_MOLARMASS ,KEY_GROUP ,
            KEY_MP , KEY_BP  , KEY_COMNAME , KEY_CONELEMENTS };
    Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iSysName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSNAME);
    int iMolarMass = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOLARMASS);
    int iGroup = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GROUP);
    int iMp = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MP);
    int iBp = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BP);
    int iCommonName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMNAME);
    int iElements = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONELEMENTS);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iSysName) + " " + c.getString(iMolarMass) + " " +c.getString(iGroup) +
                " " + c.getString(iMp)+ " " + c.getString(iBp) + " "+ c.getString(iCommonName) + " " +c.getString(iElements) + "\n";

    }
        return result;

    }







public String[] getIDSysName()
{
    String[] result = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_SYSNAME};
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        Log.d("SqlDStuff", "Cursor count: "+c.getCount());
        int iSysName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSNAME);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result[i] = c.getString(iSysName);
            i++;

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   

    }

    return result;
}

public String[] getIDGroup()
{
    String[] result2 = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_GROUP };
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iGroup = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GROUP);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result2 = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result2[i] = c.getString(iGroup);
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return result2;
}

public String[] getIDMP()
{
    String[] result3 = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_MP };
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iMp = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MP);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result3 = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result3[i] = c.getString(iMp);
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return result3;
}



public String[] getIDBP()
{
    String[] result3 = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_BP };
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iBp = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BP);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result3 = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result3[i] = c.getString(iBp);
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return result3;
}

public String[] getIDComname()
{
    String[] result4 = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_COMNAME };
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iCommonName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COMNAME);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result4 = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result4[i] = c.getString(iCommonName);
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return result4;
}
public String[] getIDElement()
{
    String[] result5 = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_CONELEMENTS };
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        int iElements = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONELEMENTS);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result5 = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result5[i] = c.getString(iElements);
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return result5;
}

public String[] getIDMOLARMASS()
{
    String[] result6 = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_MOLARMASS };
        Cursor c  =  ChemPal.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null,  null, null, null);
        int iElements = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOLARMASS);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result6 = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result6[i] = c.getString(iElements);
            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return result6;
}
}
```

Comment: a little too much code, may be. how did you made your sqlite db ?

Comment: Please consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper` rather than your own code for this. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: i made the dp using sqlite browser and ill give it a go commons ware but a bit confusing

Comment: i checked the code u suggested but it has a few errors like sqliteassetException is non exsistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling the methods as

```
sqlStuff msqlStuff = new sqlStuff(YourActivity.this);
try {
   msqlStuff.createDatabase();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
msqlStuff.openDatabase();
```

I think you may have forgotten to call the create Data base method.